# Are atomic simple C*-algebras von Neumann algebras?

Tags: operator-algebras, c-star-algebras, von-neumann-algebras

Let $A$ be a unital C$^*$-algebra such that the linear span of its projections lies norm dense, and such that below each projection there is an atomic projection. Suppose furthermore that $A$ is simple, i.e. that it has no non-trivial central elements.

Does $A$ have to be a von Neumann algebra? Since if this is true $A$ will be a type I von Neumann factor, the question reduces to: is $A$ isomorphic to $B(H)$ for some Hilbert space $H$?

A result by Kaplansky establishes this when $A$ is an AW$^*$-algebra, i.e. when its abelian subalgebras are monotone complete. Because the projections lie norm-dense the abelian subalgebras will be $\sigma$-monotone complete. Is this enough?

Comment: Do you mean "simple" (no nontrivial ideals) or "trivial centre"? They are not the same.

Comment: I meant trivial centre. I've been trying to find some results about the difference between simple and trivial centre. Could you maybe give me a reference for the difference (and if one implies the other).

Comment: If $A$ is unital, then [simple implies trivial centre](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1979969/center-of-unital-simple-c-algebra-is-mathbbc). The reverse implication is false, with the easiest example being $B(\ell^2(\mathbb N))$, which has trivial centre and the non-trivial ideal $K(\ell^2(\mathbb N))$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An easy counterexample, if the requirement is to have trivial centre,  is to take $H$ infinite-dimensional, and put $A=K(H)+\mathbb C\,I$.