# A simple $C^*$ algebra whose all idempotents are contained in a given disc

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras

Assume that $A$ is a simple $C^*$ algebra and $K>0$ is a fixed number. Assume that all idempotents $e\in A$ satisfy $|e|<K$. Does this imply that $A$ has no non trivial idempotent?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any C$^*$-algebra with trivial center that has a nontrivial idempotent has an unbounded sequence $\{e_n\}$ of idempotents.

Indeed, let $p$ be a non-trivial idempotent. This implies that there exists an idempotent $e$ that is not selfadjoint (i.e., not a projection). To see this, consider the orbit $\{apa^{-1}:\ a\ \text{ invertible}\}$. All elements are idempotents; if they were all projections, then in particular for positive invertible $a$ we would have $(apa^{-1})^*=apa^{-1}$, so $a^{-1}pa=apa^{-1}$; this gives $a^2p=pa^2$. So $p$ commutes with all squares of strictly positive elements, and so with all strictly positive elements, and then with all positive elements. As any elements is a linear combination of positives, we get that $ap=pa$ for all $a\in A$, so $p$ is central. As $A$ is assumed to be simple, [its center is trivial](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1979969/center-of-unital-simple-c-algebra-is-mathbbc), we get that $p=0$ or $p=1$, a contradiction. Thus a non-selfadjoint idempotent $e$ exists.

Given a non-selfadjoint idempotent $e$, it is not to hard to check that 
$$\tag1
p=ee^*(I+(e-e^*)(e^*-e))^{-1}
$$
is a projection, and that 
$$\tag2ep=p,\ \ \ \  pe=e. 
$$
Now let, for some $n\in\mathbb N$ 
$$\tag3
f=p+n(e-p). 
$$
The identities $(2)$ guarantee that $f^2=f$. We have 
$$
n\,\|e-p\|=\|n(e-p)\|=\|f-p\|\leq\|p\|+\|f\|=1+\|f\|. 
$$
So 
$$
\|f\|\geq n\|e-p\|-1,
$$
and so by choosing $n$ large enough we can make $\|f\|$ as large as we want.

Comment: Can I ask you read my question again.  Maybe this example helps for mor clarificatin: the matrix algebra has a sequence of idempotent approaching to infinity. I add somplicity as a hard obstruction to commutativity of algebra since idempotent of commutative algebras has norm=1. Please read the question again. The question says is it true that every simple algebra with nontrivial idem. has an unbounded sequence of idempotents?

Comment: Ok, take a look at the edit.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer.

Comment: Thanks  again for your  interesting answer. Among other things it help me to understand the proof of the classical fact that every idempotent  can be  connected to a projection. In fact $n$ in (3) can be replaced by $t\in [0,1]$. I realy enjoyed your answer.

Comment: Glad to hear that. You can actually replace  $n $ with any element in the centre. And $e $ and $p $ are always similar.

Comment: In fact (3) gives a homotopy from p to e and (2) gives Murray Von Neumman equivalent.

Comment: Yes, good point.

Comment: They are also similar, but I think that's a bit less explicit.

Comment: So it would be interesting to find a simple $C^*$ algebra whose all idempitents are projection and it has at least one non trivial projection.

Comment: For a given projection $p\in A$ it is  unlike that all $a^{-1}pa$ would  be projection for all $a\in Gl(A)$. Yes?

Comment: It only happens when  $p $ is central, so that gives you the argument you are looking for.

Comment: Yes. Thanks for your great anwer.  Any such $p$ must commute with every positive invertible element hence commute with every positive element(by consideration $\lambda +a,\; a>0 \lambda>>0$ so it commures with all things. On the other hand a simple algebra  has trivial center because it is irredicobilly embeded in some $B(H)$ hence has trivial  commutatnt. To be honnest the motivation for this question was the following: i hopped that for some algebras ee could take a disc containing all singularities of $Z'=Z^2-Z$ then a possible application of Conley index theory and isolated invariant set.

Comment: Please see this related post

Comment: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/346900/on-differential-equation-z-z2-z-on-a-c-algebra

Comment: In the first line I think you mean "Every $C^*$ algebra with trivial center"

Comment: I do, thanks! $ $